# How to store authorization token for HTTP call from Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-http, angular-http-auth

I am trying to make an HTTP call to our legacy APIs. These APIs use basic authorization.

When making a call from an Angular app, I have to pass this authorization token which is not a problem. My concern is that anyone can sniff the token from the Angular app, and that would allow them to make calls to our APIs.

How can I call existing APIs without compromising the token?

Comment: You can't. If the client-side app needs a token, the user can access it.

Comment: is there another way of doing this? To make calls to api more secure?

Comment: One way to do it is create a server in between your client app and the API, it will take care of the security concern. Remember that frontend is public anything can leak from public cookies, local storage, session storage etc.

Comment: As @TZiebura says, you need a server to proxy those requests from your client to the legacy APIs and add the token. Then the token isn't available to the client (and you can also do validation etc. before sending client data to those APIs).

Answer (score -2):

User can reach any storage on client side (example via console). So, you can not hide it.

So, You can just save this token and set to request with [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor):

- [Browser Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)
- [Browser Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
- In Service variable
- [Ngrx Store](https://ngrx.io/guide/store)